# Modulo (%) works with Decimal datatype but not with float or real. WHY?

Tags: sql, floating-point

Why modulo runs fine with decimal but not with float/real
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) states about it "**must be a valid expression of any one of the data types in the integer and monetary data type categories, or the numeric data type**." why not floating values, because it is an approximate value ??

```
--Runs fine
declare @pri decimal
set @pri = 3.25
select @pri%2
```

Result 1

```
--Gives an error 402
declare @pri float
set @pri = 3.25
select @pri%2
```

Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The data types float and numeric are incompatible in the modulo operator.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you use? The first one gives me an error in SQL Server 2000, too.

Comment: While I can't say for certain, I think you are right that the roundoff error you get from the binary IEEE754 types (float and double precision) made the language designers prohibit modulo on them.  With numeric and decimal you can specify a precision and scale.  This is just a guess, though, JavaScript and C, for example, are more than happy to let you mod on floats and doubles (it's `fmod` in C of course).

Comment: @Ocaso Protal: This is because the first tries to initialize a fixed point variable with a floating point one.

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper: Sql Server 05-08

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question about the documentation?

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx)

> dividend must be a valid expression of any one of the data types in
>   the integer and monetary data type categories, or the **numeric** data
>   type.

It says integer, monetary (money, smallmoney) and numeric

So, decimal is not supported. The documentation says "numeric is functionally same as decimal" but may be it has different meaning in some context like this one.

I guess, float is treated as numeric datatype where as decimal is not

Read the [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). It has information on monetary data types. (money, smallmoney)

**Update:**

Here is the [catagory wise data type list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx). You can follow the links to numeric and money to find what datatypes falls in it

Answer (score 1):

Because `float` and `real` represent real numbers, which can always be divided without remainder. The definition of modulo is:

`a mod n = r`, if  `a = n*q + r` , where `a`,`n`,`q` and `r` are **integers**, for the smallest possible absolute value of `r`.

Look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

For other, non-integer but fixed point variables a definition of modulo can be found, because two fixed-point values cannot always be divided without remainder. However, usually you only want to use modulo for integer arithmetic, otherwise you will get different results from what you might expect.

Comment: @Martin Smith: exactly that's what I said. Real numbers (e.g. floats) can be divided without remainder, this is why modulo is not defined for them.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve here? Modulo is an integer operator, it computes the remainder of the integer division.

If you expect 1.25 as result convert `pri` to an integer, do the division (this will give you 1) multiply by 2 and subtract the result from `pri` (3.25 - ((3/2) *2).

Comment: This question is not related to my business requirements. Its all about understanding the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the restriction is intended to protect you from unexpected results.  Modulo operations tend to give wildly unexpected results when used with inexact arithmetic.

The integer and monetary numeric types are suitable for exact arithmetic while binary floating point isn't as suitable.  For example, do you expect 0.3 % 0.01 to give you exactly zero, a number close to zero, or a number close to 0.01?  Monetary types can do this exactly.  The results using binary floating point are more surprising.